# Masonry Infinite scroll animation isn’t smooth

Tags: jquery

How can I fix the issue that my masonry infinite animate the new loaded items nicer. Now it will display directly, without a smooth animation:

```
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });

      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function( newElements ) {
// hide new items while they are loading
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
  // show elems now they're ready
  $newElems.css({ opacity: 1 });

  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
```

or This may work a bit better. (I'm assuming you are using masonry 3?).

```
function( newElements ) {
// hide new items while they are loading
var $newElems = $( newElements ).hide(); 
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
  // show elems now they're ready
  $newElems.fadeIn(); 
  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
 }
```